# How to take away the graphics in Godot 3

Tags: performance, graphics, godot

I am planning to use Godot to build games and machine learn AI's, but the graphics rendering is slowing it down too much to do train an AI. Would it be possible to temporarily take away the graphics to speed it up?

Comment: You could use a background thread for training. Then set the following attributes on the root viewport: `render_target_update_mode = Viewport.UPDATE_DISABLED` and 
 `render_target_clear_mode = Viewport.CLEAR_MODE_NEVER`. I haven't tested this, so it may not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Godot headless build or server build. Godot server is the Godot engine without graphics and sound (but can crash if you try to load an image or audio file).

Godot headless has graphics and audio modules but is meant to be executed on a terminal.